# Display Different font-size for safari mobile web

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

i am a web designer making responsive web design. All running well but problem is safari for iphone while i apply font-size of 16px it shows 23px in computed style sheet in debugger.
Give me quick suggestions to solve that one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
   body{
     -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I even applied it to `body, body *` ... what else could be wrong?